# How can I set a variable within a class to include another variable and update when the other value changes?

Tags: python, class, variables, object

I find it kind of hard to explain so this is what I mean:

```
>>> class a(object):
    a = 'z'
    b = 'b'
    c = 'c'
    all = a,b,c


>>> print a.all
('z', 'b', 'c')
>>> a.a = 'a'
>>> print a.a
a
>>> print a.all
('z', 'b', 'c')
```

How can I make `a.all` to be accurate to what is in the class
I want `a.all` to be `('a','b','c')`

I think this is because when creating a class the values are set then and there.
But I think I may need to just set the 'all' value each time i wish to access it, I just don't want to have to type out all the variables' name. This is being applied in a class with over 20 variables.

Or perhaps someone would know an efficient way to reset the 'all' variable with a function.

Comment: Do you want `a`, `b`, `c` and `all` to be properties of the *class* rather than instances? If so, why? Making `obj.all` where `obj = TheClass()` work is relatively easy, doing the same thing for `TheClass.all` is harder, partly because it's a much more obscure use case.

Comment: in this _particular_ case, you should probably be using a named tuple, rather than a class (or the mutable version of it, the Record).

Comment: Well I was doing some research in how I can create a class that I could clone, but then edit and not affect the other class, but then I also wanted the cloned class to be able to be cloned in a different way so that the second clone will be in sync with the 3rd clone. 

I was also researching on how I can get all the values returned as a list and was only told to add a function in the class that would do it. But there were complications with cloning the class and then making aliases to the clone.

Comment: Martijn Pieters, I'm new to being a stack overflow member, Id like to thank you for making my question look more presentable that was really nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `all` a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class A(object):
    a = 'z'
    b = 'b'
    c = 'c'

    @property
    def all(self):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

Note that you have to create an **instance** of the class for this to work:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.all
('z', 'b', 'c')
>>> a.a = 'a'
>>> a.all
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: This throws an error: `NameError: global name 'b' is not defined`.

Comment: @275365: Ick, I could have sworn I added in the `self.`s already. Mea Culpa.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks, this fixed the problem and it is compatible with everything I wanted to do with the class. :)

Answer (score 3):

One solution with `@property`:

```
class a(object):
    a = 'z'
    b = 'b'
    c = 'c'

    @property
    def all(self):
        return self.a, self.b, self.c

A = a()

print A.all

a.a = 'a'
print A.all
```

`@property` needs an instance instead of class.